# How do I prevent checkbox being checked if user doesn't confirm the edit?

Tags: lightning-inputfield

I have a `lightning-input` checkbox. When the user checks it, I show a `confirm` dialog. If the user confirms the edit, the checkbox should get checked and disabled. If the user *cancels*, however, the checkbox should remain unchecked. The `checked` value is based on a property of the component.

```
<lightning-input
    checked={checked}
    disabled={checked}
    label="Disclosures Sent"
    type="checkbox"
    onclick={handleClick}
></lightning-input>
```

```
handleClick() {
    this.checked = confirm('Marking disclosures as sent will lock the value.');
}
```

If I click "OK" in the dialog, the checkbox gets checked and disabled as desired, but if I click "Cancel," the checkbox is checked and enabled.

How can I set the checkbox to unchecked if the user clicks "Cancel?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `handleClick` method you should set the checked property of the element that raised the event, so you have to define an input parameter, i.e. `event`, in order to set `event.target.checked` according to the confirm's result.
I would also handle `onchange` instead of `onclick`.

**JS**

```js
checked = false;

handleClick(event) {
    this.checked = confirm('Marking disclosures as sent will lock the value.');
    event.target.checked = this.checked;
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<lightning-input
    checked={checked}
    disabled={checked}
    label="Disclosures Sent"
    type="checkbox"
    onchange={handleClick}
></lightning-input>
```

[Demo](https://studio.webcomponents.dev/edit/cufkB0L1OFtyhUDOHc9x/src/app.html?p=stories)

What happened:
Clicking on the checkbox you set the value of the element, but didn't change the value of `checked`, that remain `false` (if initialized as it), then confirm overwrite it with `false`, so the framework correctly doesn't notice a change in its value so doesn't trigger the refresh of html, that's why you have to set explicitly `target.checked`.

Comment: It wasn't the JS, it was the HTML.

Comment: @sfdcfox `onclick` fires twice, but I tested it [here](https://studio.webcomponents.dev/edit/D44vYwCK8dY1NC1pypok/src/app.js?p=stories) with `onchange` and without setting `event.target.checked` in the JS and the issue is still there, while adding that js line it's fixed

Comment: I had to do both, actually. And having to manually set `event.target.checked` doesn't make much sense to me, although it worked. Why doesn't just `checked={checked}` work?

Comment: @Chuck I edited the answer explaining what happened

Answer (score 1):

`onclick` fires for most elements even when an element is disabled.

Because you didn't handle the changing of the value, the input element still thinks it is checked. This is not specific to the component; your code would do the same thing with normal HTML.

Use `onchange` instead.

```
<lightning-input checked={checked} disabled={checked} label="Disclosures Sent" type="checkbox" onchange={handleClick}>
</lightning-input>
```

[Demo](https://studio.webcomponents.dev/edit/bFSnN6Uf15p3wbN1wllx/src/app.html?p=stories).

Edit: I just realized that you're setting this.checked to true, but the input value remains false on the first click, so the state is out of sync. When a second attempt is made, since the checked value now appears as true, it doesn't re-render the checked property, which allows the checkmark to be checked.

I've edited the demo above that demonstrates how to fix this:

```
  async handleClick(event) {
    if(confirm('Marking disclosures as sent will lock the value.')) {
      this.checked = true;
    } else {
      this.checked = true;
      await Promise.resolve();
      this.checked = false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Clicking two times on the first lightning-input in the demo, and choosing always Cancel of course, still triggers the error described in the question

Comment: @RubenDG Oh, I know what happened. That's silly. I'll make an edit.

Comment: null !== false :D
You didn't initialized `checked` to false, so the first time it worked because it's reactive

Comment: @RubenDG Yeah, that's largely irrelevant, you have to force a second render. This answer now reflects that.

Comment: that was relevant about why on the first click it worked in your demo, but not on the second one, anyway we both edited the answer explaining what happens behind the scene